# Helidon-MP (3.0.0) Metric fields for URL/path issue

Tags: helidon

Helion MP (3.0.0):
With thousands of URLs/paths to handle, and each URL/path having some injected metric fields, the performance of the Helidon server will be greatly degraded. The server would seem to get stuck handling the injected metric fields (@Inject @Metric(...) XXXX)

For details, please check out the following link:
https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/issues/6825

Send a HTTP request to the Helidon server, the server should immediately return a HTTP response; instead, the server gets stuck. it would usually take 5 to 10 minutes for the server to eventually send the HTTP response

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [your issue](https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/issues/6825) has been [addressed](https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/pull/6842).